# Copy all named ranges to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, copy, named-ranges

So I've been fussing with the Microsoft Support answer to this question but their code is simply not working. I'm confused about how they do not define x, or maybe x always equals a variable in VBA? Anyway, I am trying to copy **all** named ranges in one workbook and bring them over to another workbook. I have to do this for 50-odd workbooks and there are 30-40 named ranges in the base workbook. I really do not want to have to copy-paste these buggers manually. Here's the code they gave for this problem:

```
Sub Copy_All_Defined_Names()
   ' Loop through all of the defined names in the active
   ' workbook.
     For Each x In ActiveWorkbook.Names
      ' Add each defined name from the active workbook to
      ' the target workbook ("Book2.xls" or "Book2.xlsm").
      ' "x.value" refers to the cell references the
      ' defined name points to.
      Workbooks("trial run.xlsm").Names.Add Name:=x.Name, _
         RefersTo:=x.Value
   Next x
End Sub
```

Running this gives me the following error:

[image]

and highlights the following code:

[image]

"trial run.xlsm" is just a blank workbook and is saved as macro-enabled; this is my target workbook. Seems silly to have to ask for help debugging a macro that microsoft wrote, but I'm kinda at the end of my rope here.

For the original page I got this from, see here: [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213389/how-to-programmatically-copy-all-range-names-in-excel)

This is what my named ranges look like:

[image]

Comment: is the trial run workbook open?

Comment: Have you tried to Dim x as Range?

Comment: @EvanCallahan, you'd immediately get a type mismatch as the `Names` collection contains `Name` objects. You should dimension x, but `Dim x As Name` (and you should also give it a better variable name!)

Comment: Haha sorry about that, it was the `Name:=x.Name` part that made me think maybe x could be a range and then VBA would recognize the name of that range.  Still learning myself!

Comment: @EvanCallahan I don't blame you. It's case in point -- that's what happens if you don't name your variables carefully!

Comment: @CallumDA that's what I was wondering about. So maybe `Dim myrgnm As Name` and replace all the x's with myrgnm?

Comment: @ladymrt, because you haven't declared `x` is is implicitly a `Variant` type. When you try to use it in your for loop it is cast to a `Variant/Name`. It won't be causing a problem, because VBA understands it is a name, but avoid all confusion by declaring it as a name in the first place. Hopefully my answer clears up the main problems :)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell but I suspect that your RefersTo string is >256 characters: If so it will fail because VBA cannot handle refersto strings>256 characters.